# How do you filter users with 10+ visits in a specific time frame? Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm looking to calculate the number of unique users who've accrued 10+ sessions within a specific time frame (month), but cannot figure out how to create a segment that properly captures this. Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Segment create/edit panel - Advanced - Conditions - "Count of sessions > 9"

Here's a screenshot:

[image]